# Создание функции в Trigger postgresql

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Вот есть 2 таблицы и тип данных:

```
CREATE TABLE "Sklad" (
   "Id" serial NOT NULL,
   "Name" character varying NOT NULL,
   "Price" numeric NOT NULL,
   "Uint" character varying NOT NULL,
   "Count" bigint,
   CONSTRAINT Sklad_pk PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
) WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE "Rashod" (
   "id" serial NOT NULL,
   "Date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
   "NameSklad" character varying NOT NULL,
   "Composition" ComprositiontRashod[] NOT NULL,
   "Operator" character varying NOT NULL,
   "Total" double precision NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Rashod_pk PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (
   OIDS=FALSE
);
Create type  ComprositiontRashod AS (
   Id bigint,
   Name character varying,
   Count bigint
);
```

Дак вот пытаюсь написать триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rashod_trigger_func() RETURNS trigger AS $TRIGGER$
DECLARE
    Count bigint;
    Id bigint;
BEGIN 
    Count = (select ("Sklad".Count - u.Count) from  "Sklad", unnest(NEW."Composition") u WHERE NEW.Id = "Sklad"."Id" GROUP BY u.Count ) ;
    UPDATE "Sklad"  SET "Count"= Count  WHERE "Sklad"."Id" = 3;
    return NEW;
END;
$TRIGGER$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER rashod_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "Rashod" FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE rashod_trigger_func();
```

Он должен в таблице "Sklad" уменьшить значение 'Count' на число ушедших единиц.
Но не работает...

Comment: А что такое `u.Id = "Sklad"` ведь в двойных кавычках в данном случае это имя таблицы. Как вы колонку сравниваете с целой таблицей

Comment: Хотя как он при создании функции догадывается что такое "Rashod" для меня то же загадка

Comment: Ну видимо, я скинул немного подредактированный и стер в этом варианте id у склада, но это очевидная ошибка, есть по существу что нибудь ?

Comment: Ну текст ошибки говорит именно о том, что сравниваются несовместимые типы. и указывает как раз на ту строку с "Sklad". Если вы там id обратно написали, то эта ошибка должна была уйти